# Weird error in UITableView NSInvalidArgumentException reason: [NSNull length], when it is not null

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsnull

I am having a crush problem. This is the first thing that I couldn't find the solution online. Please help if you had same problem before. Thanks.

**Error message:**

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3a072a70'

**Here is my code:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    UILabel *lblCategoryName;
    UILabel *lblGroupName;
    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        lblCategoryName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 280, 20)];
        [lblCategoryName setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:14]];
        [lblCategoryName setTag:1];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblCategoryName];

        lblGroupName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 280, 20)];
        [lblGroupName setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Italic" size:10]];

        [lblGroupName setTag:2];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblGroupName];
    }

    POCategory *category = [self.variantCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    lblCategoryName = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    [lblCategoryName setText:category.CategoryName];

    lblGroupName = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    [lblGroupName setText:category.GroupName];

    return cell;
}
```

The weird thing is; It is working perfectly **when I comment out the following lines** OR **when my array "variant.Categories" is empty.** (I can even fill the tableview from another functions)
However it is not crushing in these lines. **And I can see the object while debugging. It is not empty.** Everything looks normal.

```
    //POCategory *category = [self.variantCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //lblCategoryName = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    //[lblCategoryName setText:category.CategoryName];

    //lblGroupName = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    //[lblGroupName setText:category.GroupName];
```

"variantCategories" array is defined like this in my UITableViewController class, and this is the only variable that I am passing to this view controller.

```
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *variantCategories;
```

I tried to make it "strong" instead of "retain" but it didn't work.

Any kind of help highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: In Xcode, set a breakpoint on exceptions. Then you see exactly where this happens. You have an object of class NSNull somewhere.

Comment: The message indicates that the `getLength` method was invoked on a null object.  Since the length method will most likely be invoked on an NSString and commenting the two setText lines addresses your issue, at a guess I would say that either GroupName or CategoryName is NSNull.  You should make sure that these two properties are defined as `strong` on your Category object

Comment: Yes the problem is category.GroupName is null. Thanks Paulw11

Comment: You should also enable NSZombies - http://michalstawarz.pl/2014/02/22/debug-exc_bad_access-nszombie-xcode-5/

Comment: @Hüseyin Avni YALÇIN :- this is same condition i am having with my project, difference is that my table view is static and i am getting this error when i start to type some thing on textField of cell :( no luck please share your experience ! here  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34264796/nsnull-length-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-on-keyboard-keystroke?noredirect=1#comment56271371_34264796)
 is my question for your reference !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message indicates that the `length` method was invoked on an NSNull object. Since the length method will most likely be invoked on an `NSString` and commenting the two `setText` lines addresses your issue, at a guess I would say that either GroupName or CategoryName is `NSNull`. You should make sure that these two properties are defined as strong on your Category object.

Comment: Actually the error states that the `length` method was called, not `getLength`. And it was called on an instance of `NSNull`, not a "null object".

Answer (score 0):

Can u Check this code it will be works:

if (cell==nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strIndentifier];
            countryLbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds)/2, 44)];
            countryLbl.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            countryLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:countryLbl];
            [countryLbl setTag:11];
            localNoLbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds)/2, 0,CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds)/2, 44)];
            localNoLbl.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            localNoLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:localNoLbl];
            [localNoLbl setTag:12];

```
    }

    [cell.contentView.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {


        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
           countryLbl = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:11];

                countryLbl.text = [countryLocArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            localNoLbl = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:12];
                localNoLbl.text=[locArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            NSLog(@"%@---%@-%@-%@",locArray,countryLocArray,countryLbl.text,localNoLbl.text);
    }
    }];
```